# Thunderbird - Add message to same folder as parent

Tags: thunderbird

I use Thunderbird 52 with an IMAP account and several dozen folders. Each time I receive a new message I have to drag it to the folder as the previous messages in the conversation. This causes some issues with threading, especially if a reply is accidentally dragged to a different folder as a previous message in the thread.

Is there any in-built functionality in Thunderbird that will move a reply to the same folder as previous messages in the thread?

I have a [Filtaquilla script](https://github.com/kgraefe/thunderbird-autotag) that adds the same tags as the parent has. Is it possible to modify this script to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any in-built functionality in Thunderbird that will move a reply to the same folder as previous messages in the thread?

I use the account setting "Place replies in the folder of the message being replied to".